# RecycleView y MDCard Kivy bug no muestra la información correctamente

Tags: python, kivy

tengo un problema con recycleView, cuando inicia mi app realizo una consulta la cual me extrae la información para visualizar en el recycle View, el recycleView en su parte viewclass tiene un MDCard de KivyMd, cuando agrego por primera vez los datos al recycleView visualiza todo de manera correctamente

> self.ids.recycle_view_data.data = [{"data":data} for data in datas]

nota: el argumento data que se pasa a la Card de recycleView es un ObjectProperty

bueno hasta aqui todo bien los datos se visualizan sin ningún problema, el problema inicia cuando vuelvo agregar los datos por segunda vez al recycleView, digamos que lo uso para mostrar datos filtrados de la lista

> filterList = []

> self.ids.recycle_view_data.data = [{"data":data} for data in filterList]

agrega los widgets solo encontrados si encontro 1, solo este dibuja un widget anterior y no al nuevo que intento agregar,  no se si recycleView carga de una manera los widgets al estilo cache que no deja borrar y confunde e inserta un widget anterior en lugar de recargar el nuevo

cabe resaltar que e probado limpiando la lista data del recycleView con data.clear() y no tengo resultados

también e visto que el ultimo ítem que carga el recycleView por primera vez y filtro un dato donde me retorne solo 1 resultado, el recycleView en lugar de dibujar al nuevo widget termina dibujando su ultimo widget que tenia anteriormente e ignora completamente el nuevo widget entrante

[image: cuando carga por primera vez los items como vemos tenemos con el id 123 a Coca Cola pero que pasa si lo busco desde el buscador y le recargo los widgets]

[image: el ultimo widget de recycleView aparente todo bien]

[image: si busco por el id encuentra 2 items pero como vemos me muestra información de widgets anteriores, por la parte del backend si retorna los datos que deben de ser]

> en la primera imagen carga por primera vez la app y carga los widget sin problema visualizando de manera correcta los datos, la segunda imagen es el ultimo widget perteneciente del recycleView, y por último la tercera imagen al cargar el dato la entidad son las correctas las filtradas, aun que ponga un metodo especial para refrescar la información en los recycleView, parece que el widget no es el perteneciente al que deseo mostrar parece ser que es un anterior ya antes cargado en el recycleView, es como si no le importara limpiar la lista data para introducir y refrescar los nuevos items entrantes

la verdad no entiendo que es lo que esta sucediendo no se si alguien pueda orientarme un poco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en caso de que alguien le pasara lo mismo, parece ser que para renderizar un kv y poder meter variables a nivel propiedades es necesario mandar los datos por separado.

en mi caso use una entidad

y lo que intentaba desde el recycleView era mandar una entidad al cuerpo de la clase

```
class Article(BaseModel):
  id:str
  name:str
class CustomMDCard(MDCard):
    article = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__():
       Clock.schedule_once(lambda *args: self.loadArticle)
    def loadArticle(self):
       self.ids.label_name.text = self.article.name
self.ids.recycleView.data[
   {"article":article} for article in listArticles
]
```

esto comete un error al refrescar las vistas a la hora de recargar datos al recycleView

mi solución fue mandar por separado los datos de la entidad

```
<CustomMdCard>:
    nameArticle:''
    MDLabel:
        id:label_name
        text:root.nameArticle
class Article(BaseModel):
    id:str
    name:str
class CustomMDCard(MDCard):
    article = ObjectProperty(None)
    nameArticle = StringProperty()
    
self.ids.recycleView.data[
   {
       "article":article,
       "nameArticle":article.name
   } for article in listArticles
]
```